# About persisting DotNetOpenAuth 4.0 client tokens

Tags: oauth, dotnetopenauth, access-token, persist

I'm working on a OAuth2.0 client with DotNetOpenAuth 4.0.0

I have a question about the the page “SampleWcf2.aspx” under the OAuth 2.0 Client sample project.

In this page, the property IAuthorizationState Authorization is remarked the following:

```
    /// <remarks>
    /// Because this is a sample, we simply store the authorization information in memory with the user session.
    /// A real web app should store at least the access and refresh tokens in this object in a database associated with the user.
    /// </remarks>
```

How to get the username of end user before I can use the CallService method?
I think if I want to save the tokens in database, then the username of end user is required as a primary key.
In my project, I use Cassandra to store tokens, and I must use username as the RowKey.

Could you get me known is there any way to get the username?

Waiting for your replies.

BR

Answer (score 1):

The username you obtain from the service provider is *not* a good primary key for your client app.  Usernames can be recycled (Yahoo! for example re-issues their abandoned usernames to new active users) and then you'd have a major privacy problem on your hands.  OAuth 2.0 isn't designed to be an authentication protocol, which is why you have this problem.

It's much better to log the user into your own site first (perhaps using OpenID 2.0, which does provide reliable claimed identifiers you can use as the primary key), *then* send them to the authorization server to obtain permission to access their private data.

In fact, in some cases you can even combine the OpenID authentication with the OAuth authorization via the OpenID+OAuth extension.  Then you get both the reliable Claimed Identifier you can use as a username, and the OAuth access token you can subsequently use to retrieve other user data.

But to answer your question from another angle, don't sweat storing the access token in your database until you know the username.  So if you do need to obtain the username from the service, use your access token (still just in memory) to call the resource server's web API to obtain the user's username (this varies depending on the service you're calling) then you have the username to store the access and refresh tokens with.